# One does not simply grep into ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, shell, grep, processbuilder, herestring

does anyone know how to use linux grep with the java ProcessBuilder? Why does this code return an empty string when it should return "sing" ?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Test2 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException,IOException{
    String line;

    // Initiate grep process.
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("grep", "\"sing\"", "<<<\"sing\"");
    Process p = pb.start();
    p.waitFor();

    // Get grep output:     
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    line = null;
    while ( (line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        builder.append(line);
        builder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    }
    String result = builder.toString();
    System.out.println(result);     
}
}
```

I also try to echo what I execute with this code:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("echo","grep", "\"sing\"", "<<<\"sing\"");
```

and get the correct result:

```
 grep "sing" <<<"sing"
```

I finally try to execute the command at the shell and get:

```
sing
```

although it is in red font for some reason. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: In your example grep is taking one argument (sing), and the `<<<` symbol tells the shell to pass whatever follows as the input stream to grep.  Your ProcessBuilder code is treating the input stream symbols as another argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what am I doing wrong?

Something which is pretty obvious.

Do you expect, say, `execve()`, to understand shell constructs? No.

Well, you shouldn't be expecting `ProcessBuilder` to understand those either. Although it is not as low level as `execve()`, it is low level enough that the arguments to a command are "raw". Therefore, in your command, `<<<"sing"` is passed as is as an argument to `grep`; which means `grep` views it as a file to read from.

Get that in your head: **what you type in the shell is interpreted by the shell**; a `ProcessBuilder` **WILL NOT** use a shell to execute its processes, nor will `execve()`. Which, in turn, means that you *cannot* use shell constructs.

If you want to `grep` you'll have to [feed your process' input](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectInput-java.lang.ProcessBuilder.Redirect-) with the text you want. But why use `grep` when Java has a builtin regex engine is another question, of course.

As to:

> although it is in red font for some reason

it is simply text decoration from the `grep` command (well, GNU grep at least); see its manpage and the `--color` option. In short, in your case, it has detected that your tty had the capabilities to change the color of text and it uses that to decorate the matched text.

Try and:

```
echo foobar | grep foo
```

It will echo `foobar` with `foo` in red.

Comment: To the answerer though you posted a correct answer, you were unnecessarily arrogant or rude to the OP disregarding the fact that what might seem obvious to you could be a mystery to the asker, if he knew then what's the point in asking?

Comment: @qualebs OK, I agree, I can rephrase my answer, but what unnerves me is that this is OS programming 101. That this sort of (non) subtlety is still not taught in programming courses in 2017 baffles me

Answer (score 1):

You can actually run the same command using `ProcessBuilder` but you have to make sure it is execute by `bash`. I prefer this utility method:

```
public static int runCmd(final String command) {
    Process process=null;
    int ret = 0;
    String[] finalCommand = new String[] { "bash", "-c", command };

    try {
        final ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(finalCommand);
        processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        process = processBuilder.start();
        ret = process.waitFor();
        // stdout+stderr
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader( process.getInputStream() );
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
          System.out.println(line);
        }
        //System.out.println("Program terminated!");
        process.destroy();
        br.close();
        isr.close();
    } 
    catch (IOException|InterruptedException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
    return ret;
}
```

Then call it as:

```
runCmd("grep -o \"sing\" <<<\"icansing\"");
```

And it gives me this **output:**

```
sing
```

Comment: Although it is a possibility, it is almost never the right thing to do; it is on the same level of badness, so to speak, as the infamous "system()"...

Comment: Well that still won't stop programmers using `system()` and to be fair there are few valid cases of doing so (not this `grep` though)

Comment: That seems like a useful method to have. Also @fge assuming that you refer to the C "system()" function, why is it so infamous? Any links you might wish to share?